# hdiutil working in terminal window but not in shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, terminal

I am using using hdiutil to mount a sparseimage file and it works fine when I type the command into terminal but when I try to run it as a shell script it gives a error.

Here is the code:

```
echo -n 'password' | hdiutil attach -stdinpass file.sparseimage
```

This is the error:

```
hdiutil: attach failed - Authentication error
```

I am sure that the password is correct. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: If the shell script uses `sh` (which is a POSIX-compliant version of `bash` in OS X), `xpg_echo` is enabled by default, so for example `echo -n password` prints `-n password` with a newline.

Comment: The -n or not shouldn't matter too much. The problem is that -stdinpass doesn't appear to work with echo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The EXAMPLES section of the `hdiutil` documentation recommends using `printf` for this rather than `echo -n`.

```
 Creating an encrypted single-partition image without user interaction:
       printf pp|hdiutil create -encryption -stdinpass -size 9m sp.dmg
```

If you are testing against 10.9 betas, do make sure to test with both the very latest version and with 10.8. I only bring this up because I have encountered some STDIN-related bugs with early version of 10.9.